# Navigating up a directory using the pack://siteoforigin

Tags: c#, wpf, pack-uri

Hi, I am trying to navigate up the folder tree to a file using `siteoforigin`. I can get to the subfolders but how do I navigate up one?

Here is the code that I have tried

```
StreamResourceInfo info = Application.GetRemoteStream(new Uri("pack://siteoforigin:,,,/../Settings.xml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. Pack Uri's can only access files within the folder that the XBAP is located and lower. No way around it, unfortunately.